# XmlParser in Gideros with Lua

Tags: lua, nsxmlparser, gideros

I'm working with Gideros and I got the error but I don't know why and how to fix.
The error is:

> attempt to index local 'xml_layout_x'

My build: http://www.mediafire.com/download/utowfooin439b66/Ex2.zip

This is my header.xml

```
<rss version="2.0">         
<layout>
    <layout_x>35</layout_x>
    <layout_y>150</layout_y>
    <layout_width>825</layout_width>

    <image>
        <width>270</width>
        <height>240</height>
    </image>

    <table>
        <layout_x>25</layout_x>

        <tablerow
            textview_name=".Name:"
            edittext_name_height="18"
            edittext_name_width="245"
            edittext_name_offset_x="150"
            textview_born=".Born:"
            textview_weight=".Weight:"
            textview_bio=".Bio:"
            edittext_bio_width="441"
            edittext_bio_height="71"
        />      
    </table>

    <action>
        <name>update</name> 
    </action>   

    <file:path bio="bio_001.txt" image="Avatar_001.png"/>
    <file:path bio="bio_002.txt" image="Avatar_002.png"/>

</layout>
</rss>
```

Then, it's my code

```
local function getChild(xml, name)
    for i=1,#xml.ChildNodes do
    if xml.ChildNodes[i].Name == name then
    return xml.ChildNodes[i]
    end
    end
    end

    -- helper function to get all children of xml node by name
    local function getChildren(xml, name)
    local result = {}
    for i=1,#xml.ChildNodes do
    if xml.ChildNodes[i].Name == name then
    result[#result + 1] = xml.ChildNodes[i]
    end
    end
    return result
    end

    info = gideros.class(Sprite)
    if info.innerSprite ~= nil then
    info:removeChild(self.innerSprite)
    end
    info.innerSprite = Sprite.new()
    info.innerSprite:setPosition(200, 10)

    local font = TTFont.new("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 38)
    local small_font = TTFont.new("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 30)

    function info:init()    
    local xml = XmlParser:ParseXmlFile("header.xml")
    local layout = getChild(xml, "layout")
    local filepath = getChildren(layout, "file:path")   

    local logo = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("logo.png"))
    self:addChild(logo)
    logo:setPosition(780, 5)    

    local Update_Btn = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("Update_Btn.png"))
    self:addChild(Update_Btn)
    Update_Btn:setPosition(33, 23)  
    Update_Btn:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, 
    function()  
    -- Get source
    local src_bio = {}
    local src_image = {}
    for i = 1, #filepath do
    table.insert(src_bio, filepath[i].Attributes["bio"])
    table.insert(src_image, filepath[i].Attributes["image"])
    end

    -- Check if file exist
    for i = 1, #filepath do
    local bio_file = io.open(src_bio[i]) 
    local image_file = io.open(src_image[i])
    if (bio_file == nil or image_file == nil) then
    table.remove(src_bio, i)
    table.remove(src_image, i)
    else
    bio_file:close()
    image_file:close()
    end
    end

    -- Get content
    local tbInfo_List = {}
    for i = 1, #src_bio do
    tbInfo_List[i] = {}
    local tbInfo_tmp1 = ReadFile(src_bio[i])
    local tbInfo_tmp2 = ConvertTable(tbInfo_tmp1)
    table.insert(tbInfo_List[i], tbInfo_tmp2)
    end

    -- Fill content
    local xml_layout_x = getChild(layout, "layout_x") *=> the error is HERE* 
    local layout_x = xml_layout_x.Value
    local xml_layout_y = getChild(layout, "layout_y")
    local layout_y = xml_layout_y.Value
    local xml_layout_width = getChild(layout, "layout_width")
    local layout_width = xml_layout_width.Value

    for i = 1, #tbInfo_List do
    local tmp_y = layout_y + layout_width*(i - 1) + 25
    table.insert(tbInfo_List[i], src_image[i])
    CreateInformationTag(layout_x, tmp_y, tbInfo_List[i], layout)   
    end
    end
    )

    local Exit_Btn = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("Exit_Btn.png"))
    self:addChild(Exit_Btn)
    Exit_Btn:setPosition(397, 23)
    Exit_Btn:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, 
    function()
    sceneManager:changeScene("home", 1, transition, easing.outBack)
    end
    )
    end

    local function CreateInformationTag(x,y, tbInfo, layout)    
    local image = Bitmap.new(Texture.new(tbInfo.image))
    local name = tbInfo.name
    local born = tbInfo.born
    local weight = tbInfo.weight
    local bio = tbInfo.bio

    --Add Image
    image.setPosition(x, y)
    self.innerSprite.addChild(image)

    local xml_image = getChild(layout, "image")
    local xml_image_width = getChild(layout, "width")
    local image_width = xml_image_width.Value()
    local xml_table = getChild(layout, "table")
    local xml_table_layout_x = getChild(xml_table, "layout_x")
    local table_layout_x = xml_table_layout_x.Value()

    local xml_table_row = getChild(xml_table, "tablerow")
    local tbTextView = {}

    -- .Name
    local xml_table_row_textview_name = getChild(xml_table_row, "textview_name")
    table.insert(tbTextView, xml_table_row_textview_name.Value())
    -- .Born
    local xml_table_row_textview_born = getChild(xml_table_row, "textview_born")
    table.insert(tbTextView, xml_table_row_textview_born.Value())
    -- .Weight
    local xml_table_row_textview_weight = getChild(xml_table_row, "textview_weight")
    table.insert(tbTextView, xml_table_row_textview_weight.Value())
    -- .Bio
    local xml_table_row_textview_bio = getChild(xml_table_row, "textview_bio")
    table.insert(tbTextView, xml_table_row_textview_bio.Value())

    local table_x = x + image_width + table_layout_x
    local table_y = y
    local table_offset_y = 20

    -- Add label
    for i = 1, 4 do
    local textfield = TextField.new(font, tbTextView[i])    
    local tmp_y = table_y + (i - 1)*table_offset_y 
    textfield:setPosition(table_x, tmp_y)
    self.innerSprite:addChild(textfield)
    end

    -- Add text box
    local edittext_name_offset_x = getChild(xml_table_row, "edittext_name_offset_x")
    local name_offset_x = edittext_name_offset_x.Value() 
    local edittext_name_width = getChild(xml_table_row, "edittext_name_width")
    local name_width = edittext_name_width.Value() 
    local edittext_name_height = getChild(xml_table_row, "edittext_name_height")
    local name_height = edittext_name_height.Value() 

    -- Draw text box
    for i = 1, 3 do
    local line = Shape.new()
    local tmp_y = table_y + table_offset_y*(i - 1)
    line:setLineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1)
    line:beginPath()
    line:moveTo(table_x + edittext_name_x,tmp_y)
    line:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x + name_width, tmp_y)
    line:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x + name_width, tmp_y + name_height)
    line:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x, tmp_y + name_height)
    line:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x, tmp_y)
    line:endPath()  
    self.innerSprite:addChild(line)
    end

    -- Draw bio text box
    local edittext_bio_width = getChild(xml_table_row, "edittext_bio_width")
    local bio_width = edittext_bio_width.Value() 
    local edittext_bio_height = getChild(xml_table_row, "edittext_bio_height")
    local bio_height = edittext_bio_height.Value() 

    local line_bio = Shape.new()
    line_bio:setLineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1)
    line_bio:beginPath()
    line_bio:moveTo(table_x + edittext_name_x,tmp_y)
    line_bio:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x + bio_width, tmp_y)
    line_bio:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x + bio_width, tmp_y + bio_height)
    line_bio:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x, tmp_y + bio_height)
    line_bio:lineTo(table_x + edittext_name_x, tmp_y)
    line_bio:endPath()  
    self.innerSprite:addChild(line_bio)

    -- Add text in box
    for i = 1, 3 do
    local textfield = TextField.new(small_font, tbInfo[i])  
    local tmp_y = table_y + (i - 1)*table_offset_y 
    textfield:setPosition(table_x, tmp_y)
    self.innerSprite:addChild(textfield)
    end

    -- Add wrap text
    local tw = TextWrap2.new(tbInfo[4], table_x, table_y + 2*table_offset_y , 18, small_font)
    self.innerSprite:addChild(tw)
    end


    function ReadFile(filename)
    local tbInfo = {}
    fp = io.open(filename, "r")

    for line in fp:lines() do
    table.insert(tbInfo, line)
    end 
    fp:close()
    return tbInfo
    end

    function ConvertTable(tbInfo)
    local tmp = {}
    for i = 1, #tbInfo do
    if (i <= 4) then<br />   table.insert(tmp, tbInfo[i])
    else
    local str1 = tmp[5]
    local str2 = tbInfo[i]
    table.remove(tmp, 5)
    local str = str1 + str2
    table.insert(tmp, str)
    end
    end
    return tmp
    end
```

Comment: I attached my build on my question, thanks :)

Comment: Try to post a minimal example that shows the erroneous behavior.

Comment: I finally found out the source of the error, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem :D
The xml file causes the error when parsing. Thanks all